# How to inject a React component asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use this library https://developers.timekit.io/docs/booking-widget-v2#getting-started and in the instruction set it mentioned: "This is ideal for usage in single page applications like Angular.js, where you'd injecting  async in your template and control it through JS in your controller/directive/component code." [image: instantiation instruction] How exactly do I do that? This is what my approach so far, but it is not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import TimekitBooking from 'timekit-booking';

const App = () => {
  let widget = new TimekitBooking();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      {widget
        .init({
          app_key: 'test_widget_key_0rZsWpUP40J8jXFgU6odRQexukqAxCYu',
          project_id: 'fc81fa67-eaef-4c49-af64-f908fced2714',
        })
        .then(() => {
          return <div id="bookingjs"></div>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

expor
```

t default App;

Comment: they have a fiddle showing how to do this in React. [See Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jbmafr97/)